# mysql select statement from multiple statement

Tags: mysql

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SET @db_names:='';
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @db_names=app_id THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,@db_names:=app_id AS db_names
FROM master_order 
ORDER BY app_id ;
```

When I run this statement it gives me result.

I want it like

```
select *from (SET @row_number:=0;
SET @db_names:='';
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @db_names=app_id THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,@db_names:=app_id AS db_names
FROM master_order 
ORDER BY app_id ) as temp

where row_number = 1;
```

I want to select the first row of duplicate columns

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this like this:

```
SELECT * FROM master_order
ORDER BY app_id = '' DESC, app_id
LIMIT 1;
```

But for clarification on how it would've worked if this simplification would not be possible, either this way:

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SET @db_names:='';

select *from (
    SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @db_names=app_id THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,@db_names:=app_id AS db_names
    FROM master_order 
    ORDER BY app_id 
) as temp
where row_number = 1;
```

or this:

```
select *from (
    SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @db_names=app_id THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,@db_names:=app_id AS db_names
    FROM master_order 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0, @db_names := '') var_init
    ORDER BY app_id 
) as temp
where row_number = 1;
```

Comment: what does this achieve? **ORDER BY app_id = '' DESC**

Comment: `app_id = ''` is either true or false, 1 or 0. The OP wants to have the first occurence where app_id is an empty string, therefore we sort descending the mentioned boolean expression and then by app_id, cause OP wants to have the first app_id that's not empty.